# Grails + Idea module project

Tags: maven, grails, intellij-idea, gradle, module

I want to spread my grails application into several modules.
For example,

- i want to cteate one **CoreModule** it will has domain classes and
  base services.
- Then **AdminPanelModule** and **RestServiceModule**.
  They will has own controllers and own specific services. But they
  have to get access to CoreModule's domain classes and services.

Than I want to deploy 2 CoreModule apps, and 1 AdminPanelModule app on different hosts. Help me plz.

1. How can I organize dependencies with Idea?
2. What i need to do, to create correct run configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing internal Grails modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777930/accessing-internal-grails-modules)

Comment: See the above, as it answers your questions on how to properly build a grails application which is broken down into modules.